# Why two Static object inside an operator overload implementation will always be equal in c++?

Tags: c++, object, static

I was readin effective c++. They have given an example as below :

```
class Rational{
    public : Rational (int num=0, int deno=1);
    private : int n,d;
              friend Rational operator*(const Rational &lhs, const Rational &rhs);

 }


 Rational& operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs)
 {
     static Rational result;
     result = f(lhs.n*rhs.n, lhs.d*rhs.d) //some function f which multiply num 
                                          //and denom which returns Rational type

      return result;
 }

  bool operator==(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs);

  int main()
  {
        Rational a,b,c,d;
        .....
        if((a*b)==(c*d)){
        ....
        }
        else {
        .....
        }
  }
```

Why the compariosion (a*b)==(c*d) always evaluate to true?

The == operator will be evaluated as if(operator==(operator*(a,b),operator*(c,d)))
Effective C++ says - the operator == will be asked to compare the value of static Rational object inside operator * with the value of the static Rational object inside * operator. Why these static values will always be equal?

Comment: Result should be a local variable, not static. Also your operator== is missing, maybe it's just `return true` ;)

Comment: Your title shows your confusion. There aren't two static objects, only one. That's the meaning of static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both expressions in this comparison `((a*b)==(c*d))` return a reference to the same object - `static Rational result` from inside `operator*`. It has static storage duration and it lives from the moment the execution flow reaches it for the first time and until the program exits (in other words, it persists between the calls to `operator*`).

Unless the `operator==` does something weird, an object is supposed to be equal to itself and the result will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

Because a static variable in a function is unique for all the calls to this function. It means that it doesn't matter when or on which object (for member functions) the function is called, the variable which is static will be unique, and keep its value between the calls (while local variables will be constructed and destroyed respectively at the beginning and at the end of the function.

In your case, this will happen:

- First, both `operator*(a,b)` and `operator*(c,d)` are called
- In each call, the value of your static variable will be updated, so the variable, which is unique, will be updated twice *before the comparison* (this is important)
- Then, the operator compares the values returned by both calls, which is a reference to the static variable (and it ends up being a comparison of this variable with itself)

Comment: @jrok Removed it temporarily, but shouldn't the call order follow the `==` associativity ? It doesn't change the result anyway (but that's worth pointing out, thank you)

Comment: Associativity doesn't neccesarily imply order of evaluation. It means, for example of left-associative operator, that `a == b == c` is the same as `(a == b) == c` and not `a == (b == c)`.

Answer (score 1):

As the operator* returns reference to the same static object, operator== simply compares this object with itself. And so, always return true.